# Button not being adjusted programmatically

Tags: swift, button, adjustment

I have a button called loginButton and I want to change its frame position and have tried several ways. One method is this:

```
var newFrame = loginButton.frame;
newFrame.origin.y -= 100; 
loginButton.frame = newFrame;
```

The other method is this:

```
loginButton.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 16, y: 204)
```

None of these seem to do the job. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've already positioned this button using autolayout constraints. You cannot fight against autolayout with `frame` settings. If you want to reposition the button, you must change the *constraints*.